# Difference between curry and curryRight in Lodash

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, currying

What is the difference between `curry` and `curryRight` in Lodash?

Is just the application order of the provided arguments switched from `f(a,b,c)` which applies to `f(a) -> f(b) -> f(c)` to `f(a,b,c)` which then applies to `f(c) -> f(b) -> f(a)`?

I already looked into the Lodash documentation but that didn‘t helped me.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. It is also the conceptually same as `_.curry(_.flip(f));`.

Comment: The documentation has some examples. Is there is any particular example that you are confused by?

Comment: I guess if one is the right way of currying, the other must the wrong one :D

Comment: Bergi, you made my day

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#curry):

```
var abc = function(a, b, c) {
  return [a, b, c];
};

var curried = _.curryRight(abc);

curried(3)(2)(1);
// => [1, 2, 3]

curried(2, 3)(1);
// => [1, 2, 3]

curried(1, 2, 3);
// => [1, 2, 3]
```

The first example is simple. The order of the arguments is reversed (in comparison to _.curry).

The second and third one can perhaps be confusing.

In the third example we see that the order of the arguments is NOT reversed. That is because only the *currying* is applied in reverse. In other words the parentheses are applied in the reverse order, but what is inside of the parentheses sustains the original order.

Compare this to the result of `_.curry(_.flip(f))`:

```
var abc = function(a, b, c) {
  return [a, b, c];
};

var curried = _.curry(_.flip(abc), 3);
    
curried(3)(2)(1);
// => [1, 2, 3]

curried(3, 2)(1);
// => [1, 2, 3]

curried(3, 2, 1);
// => [1, 2, 3]
```

As you can see the result is **different**. Now the order of the arguments is reversed totally in all the examples.

Btw notice that for some reason I needed to specify the arity to 3 in `_.curry(_.flip(abc), 3);`. I don't know why but it causes an exception without that.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. Indeed it was the last example in the documentation that confused me. But now I got it :)